# Add sequential character to id

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Looking to add a sequential number to the id currently its `'_s'` so that when multiple instances of the id are generated it would have a unique id.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

```
public function calculate_shipping($package = array())
{
    // error_log(json_encode($this->_rates));
    if (isset($this->_rates['shipping_standart']) && isset($this- 
 >_rates['shipping_standart']['cost'])) {
        $rateData = array(
            'id'       => $this->id . '_s',
            'label'    => 'Standard',
            'cost'     => $this->_rates['shipping_standart']['cost'] / 
 100,
            'calc_tax' => 'per_order'
        );

        $this->add_rate($rateData);
    }
}
```

Comment: How/where is the ID created?

Comment: Do the number have to be sequential? You could add the current timestamp.

Comment: @Dave @José A. Zapata - I was able to generate a random character using this `'id'       => $this->id . chr(rand(65,90)) ,` but I need a sequential number or character not a random one.